# Angular material theme variables

Tags: css, angular, themes, scss-mixins

I have an app with multiple theme files, where during run time I select / specify the theme.

```
.client1-theme{
    // @include angular-material-theme($client1-theme);  
    @include all-component-colors($client1-theme);
    @include theme-color-grabber($client1-theme, $client1-alternate);
    @include status-background($client1-theme);
    @include spinner-color($client1-theme);

}

.client2-theme{
    @include all-component-colors($client2-theme);
    @include theme-color-grabber($client2-theme, $client2-alternate);
    @include status-background($client2-theme);
    @include spinner-color($client2-theme);

}
```

I have set of scss variables stored in another file colors.scss where I define variables such as

```
$primary: mat-color($client1-primary);
$accent: mat-color($client1-accent);
$alternate: mat-color($client1-alternate);
```

This allows me to import the colors.scss file in my components and use the variables in component scss file.

Now based on the theme selection I am looking to find a method of changing the values of these variables such as for client2-theme the variables should be

```
$primary: mat-color($client2-primary);
$accent: mat-color($client2-accent);
$alternate: mat-color($client2-alternate);
```

The idea being based on the selected theme, the component scss file use the right colors / variable values. I tried to defined global classes through mixin but that doesnt allow me to use @extend in the component file.

Any suggestions on how this could be achieved  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing similar issue

I ended up writing a mixin which overrides the component styles from the global scss file and applying the mixin for the each of the themes.